# Maintain secure session using PhoneGap

Tags: security, session, cordova, session-variables, state

I have a simple jQuery mobile PhoneGap application which uses ajax call to server to authenticate a users credentials against servers db (uses CORS).

Once user is authenticated I setup some local storage variables for the session but I suspect this is not a secure method of maintaining state.

I'm wondering if there is a better & more secure way to keep track of the users session state. At the moment I'm thinking of implementing some kind of token based handshake between the app & the server for each subsequent server call post logon. I'm hoping there is a better more standard way to implement secure sessions in PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shouldn't save origin credentials in local storage. At first, you should encrypt credentials by your encrypt algorithms and you can save it in local storage or preference(Android/iOS - best is store in preference) or anywhere you want. If another person get credentials, it have been encrypt, they not use it to authenticate with server(Only you had decrypt algorithms).
Continue, you must do something to prevent other person decompile your app. They will have your decrypt algorithms and use it to decrypt credentials-->origin credentials-->post to server success.
Have many way to secure your app, you can search and research.
Code demo in Android:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("account", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
user = your_encrypt(username);
pass = your_encrypt(password);
//encrypt and save account
editor.putString("username", user);
editor.putString("password", pass);
editor.commit();
//get account
String u = sharedPref.getString("username", "");
String p = sharedPref.getString("password", "");
//decrypt username/pass
username = your_decrypt(u);
password = your_decrypt(p);
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly the suggestion is to encrypt the credentials and then store them in local storage and then decrypt them for server calls?

Comment: you can do that. But i think you shouldn't store in local storage because another person can to access and change your credentials. You should store in Preferences(xml) or database in your app and only you can access it.